# Alternative to media9 package for embedding MP4 videos in LuaLaTeX PDF

Tags: media9, multimedia

I have a presentation from 2 years ago which embeds MP4 videos into a PDF document generated with LuaLaTeX using the `multimedia` and `media9` packages. Now, two years later, the document is still generated without issues, but my PDF viewer `evince` does no show the videos. I assume that is because of the removal of Flash support, which seems necessary for the kind of embeddings (or what are they? The document used to not work when separated from the videos, I think, so I assume the movie is not actually packaged with the PDF) used by `media9`.

My embedding commands look like

```
  \movie[width=\textwidth,height=0.7\textwidth
      ]{\includegraphics[height=0.7\textwidth]{Bruder.png}
    BRUDER\footnote[frame]{Boyes Braem, P. (1992)}
  }{bruder.mp4}
```

What is the laziest replacement for `media9` I can use to make these video embeddings work again?

Comment: For Evince, the only option seems to be `\href{run:bruder.mp4}{\includegraphics[height=0.7\textwidth]{Bruder.png}}`, that is, playback in an external video player.

Comment: Hm, time to look at some other PDF viewers then.

Comment: Did you check out Okular?

Comment: No, for now I had assumed that I want to solve the problem on the TeX side, but I will check it now.

Comment: You can't really solve this in the TeX side. Features like media playback and JavaScript are viewer-dependent and mostly unsupported/not implemented. Acrobat and Okular are the viewers which do support the majority of what you would want to do with PDF.

Comment: @TeXnician It does work with Okular, thank you very much. If you want to turn that into a frame challenge answer, I will accept it.

Comment: I have converted my comment into an answer.

Comment: Are you saying, that Evince successfully played your video two years ago, but now stopped to do so?

Comment: @KurtPfeifle That is what I am saying. Flash support was removed, so Evince can't use flash support any more to play videos like it could two years ago.

Comment: @Anaphory I doubt that Evince has ever been able to play media in an embedded fashion.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can't really solve this on the TeX side. Features like media playback and JavaScript are viewer-dependent and mostly unsupported/not implemented. Acrobat and Okular are the viewers which do support the majority of what you would want to do with PDF.

Comment: Except PDF Layers. Here, Evince outpaces Okular.

Comment: @AlexG That might be, but is LaTeX able to really make use of them (I only remember ConTeXt doing that)?

Comment: Package ocgx2 provides everything needed.